# Keeping CIFS mount over unstable WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, samba, freenas, cifs, crashplan

I have a FreeNAS box that contains all of my music and movies. Since I want this box accessible to both myself (Linux desktop) and my wife (Windows desktop) I have the filesystems on this box exported via a "Windows share" (i.e. Samba), which worked fine when there was a wired connection between my desktop and the FreeNAS box. Now they are connected over WiFi via a Netgear Orbi system, and it seems like the connection between them goes down every so often. When this happens, the filesystems become inaccessible, even after the connection comes back, and my Crashplan backup reports these filesystems as "missing".

How do I make it so a temporary disruption in the connection doesn't kill the mounted filesystems on my desktop?

Comment: Are you sure it's not changing IP address and infact this interuption isn't a DHCP renewal with a new IP? Smb should automatically reconnect when accessed, so something isn't right here.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I'm not sure *all* implementations of SMB will automatically reconnect after a temporary disconnection?

Answer (score 1):

SMB transparent reconnect is available from SMB dialect 2.1. This was especially intended to keep transfers over unstable (wifi) connections. Which SMB is your FreeNAS supporting? Maybe you can upgrade it to support 2.1+?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I find out what version of SMB my NAS supports?

Comment: Use wireshark to take packet capture and inspect yhr very first SMB which is Negotiate